# Completar dados de 1 tabela buscando informações em uma segunda tabela sem adicionar linhas a mais na primeira tabela

Tags: mysql

**Informações iniciais:**

- Estou utilizando o MySQL;
- tabela1 possui 1.000 linhas e é a minha tabela principal;
- tabela2 possui 400 linhas e contém as informações adicionais que preciso completar na tabela1
- O campo chave entre as duas tabelas é o Cod_Cli
- na tabela 2 existem 50 Cod_Cli que não estão na tabela1 e espero não adicioná-los na pesquisa.

**O que preciso:**
Gostaria de buscar informações na tabela2 desde que o Cod_Cli seja igual **e exista na tabela 1**.
Os Cod_Cli da tabela2 que não estejam na tabela1, não deverão ser adicionados na pesquisa, ou seja, preciso que o resultado da pesquisa seja sempre igual a 1.000 linhas.

**Problema:**
Ao executar a query abaixo, utilizando o left join, o resultado da pesquisa sempre é de 1.050 linhas, ou seja, esta pesquisa está adicionando os Cod_Cli da tabela2 que não estão na tabela1.

Segue a query que estou utilizando e que está adicionando as 50 linhas comentadas acima e que esperava não adicioná-las.

**SELECT T1.Cod_Cli, T1.nome, T2.OCUPAÇÃO
FROM T1 LEFT JOIN T2
on T1.Cod_Cli=T2.Cod_Cli**

***Pergunta**: Sou bastante novo na utilização do MySQL. O que estou precisando adaptar na query acima para poder resolver essa pesquisa? Isso me parece simples, mas já pesquisei bastante e não encontrei algo que eu conseguisse resolver na prática, pois em minhas tentativas alterando a query acima, sempre aparecem erros de sintaxe.*

Comment: Você conferiu as tabelas para ver se os valores a mais são mesmo de códigos que não estão em T1? Podem ser códigos que estão se repetindo, caso as chaves de T2 não forem únicas.

Comment: Você tem razão. Os 50 itens adicionais são exatamente a quantidade de chaves que estão se repetindo na T2. Muito obrigado pelo alerta e pela solução do problema. Você tem alguma sugestão para juntar, por exemplo, o campo "Descrição" quando a chave se repetir numa tabela?

Comment: Acabei de resolver este tema de concatenar determinado campo quando houver chaves duplicadas em uma tabela.  Utilizei:   SELECT Cod_Cli, GROUP_CONCAT(Descr_Cli separator ',') as Descrição FROM T2 group by Cod_Cli